# Difference when creating git sharing tag

Tags: git

When I want to create a sharing tag.http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-6.html#Sharing-Tags

I have two ways to do this.

1. **git push origin [tagname]**
2. **git push origin HEAD:refs/tags/[tagname]**

What's the difference between them?
Thanks

Comment: where did you find the second one?

Comment: @NevikRehnel See [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Answer (score 0):

The first pushes a local tag to a remote tag (and creates it if it doesn't exist).

The latter pushes `HEAD` to a remote tag (and creates it if it doesn't exist).  There is not necessarily a local tag.

See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_examples for canonical examples of the complex syntax variants for refspecs (note that this is pretty much the same for tags as it is for normal references).